Removing a vertex and all its neighbors in a graph
I'm implementing an approximation algorithm to compute "maximum" independent sets. It requires that I remove a minimum degree vertex and all its neighbors.
I can find the vertex of minimum degree of a graph g like so:
minDegreeVertex = Ordering[VertexDegree[g], 1]

Now I can compute it's neighborhood via
h = NeighborhoodGraph[g, minDegreeVertex]

and I've attempted the following to do what I need:
VertexDelete[g, h]

GraphDifference[g, h]

None of these do what I want. The first one throws an error and the second one only removes edges for some reason.
This is my first time using Mathematica so I thank you all in advance for your answers.

Did you try VertexDelete[g, VertexList[h]]?

Thank you it worked! Now I'm stuck writing the loop, but I'll probably ask another question in a while if I don't manage to get it running.

VertexDelete[g, VertexComponent[g, minDegreeVertex, 2]] is faster.
